# Why do we introduce $\forall$ in first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Let $T$ be a first-order theory. It is a classical metatheorem that $T\vdash \varphi$ if and only if $T \vdash \forall x \varphi$ where $x$ is a variable and $\varphi$ a well-formed formula.

For me that means that $\varphi$ and $\forall x \varphi$ have exactly the same power in proofs. Therefore why did we introduce $\forall$ in the first place ?

Comment: Because there are formulas that not holds if universally quantified: $(n=0)$ in arithmetic.

Comment: The metatheorem above holds **provided that** $x$ is not free in $T$. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688384/why-is-alpha-rightarrow-forall-x-alpha-not-generally-correct-in-first-ord?rq=1).

Comment: Because "*not all people passed the logic exam*" ($\neg\forall x.P(x)$) and "*all people did not pass the logic exam*" ($\forall x. \neg P(x)$) are two very different scenarios, and without introducing $\forall$, we would only be able to discuss the latter.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA : Thanks to the generalization rule, we get $T \vdash \forall x \varphi$ from $T \vdash \varphi$ even if $x$ is free in $T$. There is no condition in that rule. Or am I mistaken ?

Comment: But not for the other implication; thus, if you state **iff** you have to add the proviso.

Comment: Also, think about quantifier alternations: even ignoring the issues above, how would you approach something like $\forall x\exists y\forall z\exists w[stuff]$?